# mediapipe hair segmentation in Javascript

Tags: mediapipe

How would I convert [this demo](https://viz.mediapipe.dev/demo/hair_segmentation) into a standalone script that runs in the background without needing to press the 'run' button or display the code?  I've inspected the source, but the JS all seems to be minified and hard to decipher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only android and c++
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaXld.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).